# Need guidance: will reapplying help?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I'm an IT professional for over 20 years. I lived in the US for 6 years, and I also happen to be a gifted musician with some awards and recognition. 3 years ago, we were invited by an organization in the UK for a music performance and we applied for a Tier-5 visa, musician, failing to submit any additional documents like newspaper clippings, pics, awards as well as bank statements, employment details etc.

The visa was refused, stating that I hadn't submitted any evidence. This year we applied for a visitor's visa, on my friend's invitation, a British citizen. To overcome last time's mistake, we submitted all the documents like employment leave letter, bank statements, payslips, returns, assets etc. In spite of this, it was refused, stating that I had not disclosed about my IT employment when we applied as a musician last time in 2015, and that I don't have a genuine intention of returning. It added to the overall disappointment in the process.

Please suggest if a cover letter with a detailed profile, including all the companies I worked for, awards etc and re-applying will help, as I'm genuine and I don't have any plans to overstay? I have visited many countries multiple times along with having a US business visa without any issue.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should ask a UK immigration lawyer for help.

Comment: Agree with @phoog . You appear to have two separate refusals. Get a lawyer with specific experience in UK immigration/visas.

Comment: 'You're writers?' the citizeness asked in her turn.
'Unquestionably,' Koroviev answered with dignity.
"Your identification cards?' the citizeness repeated.
'My sweetie ...' Koroviev began tenderly.
'I'm no sweetie,' interrupted the citizeness.
'More's the pity,' Koroviev said disappointedly and went on.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to the immigration officers wanting to be sure you're really doing what you say, and omitting this IT job might look 'suspicious' to them.

You need to allay this suspicion. Evidence of a contract in your home city, an apartment lease, a letter from your employer showing your intention to return to your job, all these go a long way towards giving them comfort in the certainty you may return.

Saying that, after your previous two rejections, they are probably likely to be stricter in their checks.  Make sure not to leave anything out, even if it's just extra information, and consider getting an immigration lawyer / specialist to assist you with your application.